# Data is not being transferred from one custom directive to another if we use $http to fetch data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, youtube-api

I have two different custom directive and wanted to pass data from one directive to another. The data is coming from server call. Problem is http being a asyn call doesn't return data upfront and controller of another widget doesnt receive it and it renders it's html without having it. here is the complete code (I have removed some code that might not make sense in the problem)-

The service which hits server is -

```
angular.module('myModule')

    .service('MyService', [
        '$http',

        function($http) {
            this.getData = (someId) => {
                var url = someUrl + '/' + someId;
                return  $http.get(url);
            };
        }
    ]);
```

and the first directive that calls service and set "anotherData" in the scope to be transferred to another directive is -

```
angular.module('myModule')

    .directive('myDirective', ['MyService',
        function(MyService) {

        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                data: '='
            },
            templateUrl: 'my-template.html',

            controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {

                MyService.getData ($scope.data.id).then((response) => {
                    $scope.anotherData = response.data;
                });

        }]
    }

}]);
```

and my-template.html from which i am calling another directive is (notice anotherData is passed here -

```
<other-directive mode="display" data="data" anotherData="anotherData" ></other-directive>
```

The other directive that should receive "anotherData" but giving me no result is -

```
angular.module('otherModule')

    .directive('otherDirective', [function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                id: '@',
                data: '=',
                mode: '@',
                anotherData: '@'
            },
            templateUrl: 'other-template.html',

            controller: ['$scope', '$element', function ($scope, $element) {

                console.log("other data in widget after server call:");
///THIS IS UNDEFINED.
                console.log($scope.anotherData);
            }],

            link: function ($scope, $element) {
        }
    }
}]);
```

and other-template.html has iframe to display youtube widget -

```
<iframe width="{{anotherData.videoWidth}}"
        height="{{anotherData.videoHeight}}"
        src="{{anotherData.videoURL}}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Not sure what you need to do with this data, but of course it will be undefined at that stage since `anotherData` is not yet received from the server. When it's received, if you handled the binding correctly, it should render in the HTML. You should probable share some more of your code.

Comment: added the html in which I am creating a youtube widget. probably i need data upfront.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use dashes instead of camel case, like this:

```
<other-directive mode="display" data="data" another-data="anotherData" ></other-directive>
```

Also, you are binding for text instead of two-way binding an object, so change the definition in your directive to this:

```
anotherData: '='
```

Comment: After doing camel case and = operator; it solves both of my issues. So two way binding and camel casing was the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick

```
<other-directive another-data=anotherData></other-directive>
```

You need to be caarefull with the camel case in html!

Comment: I tried this. data transfered but wont work as i want data at the time of rendering page. is there a way to make http call sync?

Comment: Angular itself doesnt have sync calls. Maybe you could do it with jQ Ajax. But i would strongly recommend not doint it. Because its just the easy way out -- maybe you could use resolve in a higher lvl controller?